# Dynamic computed properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a pojo class whose properties needs to be dynamically calculated. Example

```
public class User{
   
   @Getter
   @Setter
   public String firstName;

   @Getter
   @Setter
   public String lastName;
    
   @Getter
   @Setter
   public String emailId;
}
```

Here the emailId needs to be computed as

```
emailId = firstName + lastName +"@domain.com"
//or
emailId = firstName + empId +"@domain.com";
//or
emailId = firstName + "." +lastName +"@domain.com"
// it could be any combination
```

I have exposed an API which accepts json of name value pair which looks like this:

```
{
    "firstName" : "Mark",
    "lastName" : "Hazel",
    "empId" : "201",
    "dept" : "IT",
}
```

notice some of the fields in the json are not present in the pojo class User, but can be indirectly involved in computing the emailId field.

I wanted to externalize this computation into some config file(Each per customer) so that every customer can have their definition of emailId computation expression.

I have checked spring expression language, but the examples I saw was based on static computation in the **@Value** annotation. Moreover, the fields involved in the computation need to be the fields in the pojo.
I have also tried ObjectMapper, but couldn't find a way to do such kind of configuration based computation.

I would like to hear from the experts here what would be the cleanest way to achieve the above.
I will be using this same approach for other pojo classes, so want to make it a generic solution.

Comment: You can only use `@Value` in spring managed objects. You can however create a spring managed factory that injects the `Environment`. As for the jackson marshalling, why not create a getter that does the concatenation? I mean, no need to store a dynamically created value in a field, just compute it when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose variables to external config, you can use Handlebars, even tho its not ment to be used that way, its one of the options.
Lets say you have config file with content:

```
{{firstName}}.{{lastName}}@domain.com
```

You can load this String or file into Handlebars and pass your DTO into handlebars as Map.

```java
Handlebars handlerBars =  new Handlebars();

// Convert POJO to Map
Map<String, Object> parameterMap = mapper.convertValue(user, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

// Template, can be loaded from file or DB
String template = "{{firstName}}.{{lastName}}@domain.com";

// Compile Template
Template emailIdTemplate = handlerBars.compileInline(template);

// Apply Variables
String emailId = emailIdTemplate(parameterMap);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way I can give the config to a deserializer so that it may auto compute the properties while deserialization into the pojo

Comment: You can add this functionality inside your POJO with @JsonProperty to auto calculate. Method should return your emailId.

Comment: That would make the computation static. Can we externalize the @JsonProperty expression in the config file?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what you are trying to achieve. This implementation is more than enough for any dynamic generations.

Comment: The formula for computing the email id can be dynamic, It could be 
{{firstName}}.{{lastName}}@domain.com or
{{firstName}}.{{empId}}@domain.com
what I infering to is using @jsonproperty will make formula of computation  static.
I wanted this formula to be in config.

Comment: you can put this String anywhere you want, in config files, in db row, it's up to you where to store it, and what variation of it (per tenant, per user, per group, etc)